# Excess vertical space between theorem and proof inside enumerate/itemize

Tags: spacing, theorems

I have a claim followed by its proof (both inside an enumerate environment). As you can see I'm getting some additional space between the claim and proof only when they are inside the enumerate. What's the reason and how to get rid of that annoying space?

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newtheorem*{claim}{Claim}

% \usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}
    \begin{enumerate}[label = (\alph*)]
        \item This text is before the claim.
        % 
        \begin{claim}
            \let \qed \relax
            Our claim goes here.
            \label{clm:1.a)}
        \end{claim}
        % 
        \begin{claim}
            \let \qed \relax
            Our claim goes here.
            \label{clm:1.b)}
        \end{claim}
        % 
        \begin{proof}
            Here we prove our claim.
        \end{proof}
    \end{enumerate}
    % 
    \rule{\linewidth}{2pt}
    % 
    This text is before the claim.
    % 
    \begin{claim}
        \let \qed \relax
        Our claim goes here.
        \label{clm:2.a)}
    \end{claim}
    % 
    \begin{claim}
        \let \qed \relax
        Our claim goes here.
        \label{clm:2.b)}
    \end{claim}
    % 
    \begin{proof}
        Here we prove our claim.
    \end{proof}
\end{document}
```